# What does 'Session is either stored in a cookie on the user side or is propagated in the URL' mean?

Tags: php

What does `propagated in the URL` mean?

Is that like the `GET` method? Can you give me an example?

Comment: It means the session is sent via the URL. Please clean up your question and add more scope to it.

Comment: Is my question wrong? does it hurt you?

Comment: that's session id, session data is stored on the server

Comment: It does not hurt me, it hurts the site. Please don't take this personally. Please read this entry on how to ask a good question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask We are only trying to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

```
http://example.com/somepage?sid=0123456789abcdef
```

Answer (score 0):

It means the session ID is sent as part of the URL (a GET parameter)